# Android: stop scrolling when imageview is touched?

Tags: java, android, scroll, imageview

I try to make it possible to rotate an ImageView, but the scrolling gets in my way. How can I stop the scrolling while the ImageView is touched? I don't think that code is necessary, but here is goes:
**fragment_main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
        android:background="@drawable/texture">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Πάγωσε η κόλαση..."
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_0"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Μπρρρ!"
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Κρύο"
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="75dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Έτσι κ'έτσι..."
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_3"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Καλό"
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="125dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Πολύ καλό!"
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Κάνεις κοιλιακούς!"
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/label_6"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/thermostat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thermostat"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/thermostat_slider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thermostat_slider"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/inside_thing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inside_thing"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/inside_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/inside_text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Τι κάνω?"
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_margin"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="@string/help_text"
            android:textColor="@color/label_color"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="750dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable the scrolling of a `ScrollView`. You would need to extend to ScrollView and override the `onTouchEvent` method to return false when some condition is matched.

```
public class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {
private boolean mScrollable=true;
    public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

Override required methods and constructors

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
                if (mScrollable) return super.onTouchEvent(ev); //return mScrollable condition is false

/*
*Write your code here to implement your functionality like if you image view is touched
*/
                    // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
                    return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
    // mScrollable flag may  help you 
//use it as a condition
                    default:
                        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                }
            }




@Override  
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {     
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:         
        // if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass      
        if (mScrollable) return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);      
        // only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled    
        return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point     
        default:          
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);      
            }
    }
```